# OOP mutli lang, make file to be included

Tags: php, oop, include

So I want to make my page to have multi language function, like German, English, and Hungarian. I started to learn OOP in PHP, and now I force myself to use OOP in everything, sure not a good idea, but I try to learn. So this is what I got so far:

```
<?php

class class_lang {

    private $language;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->language = $_GET['lang'];
    }

    public function select_lang($var);

        return ('language_'.$this->select_lang($var));
}

?>
```

So what is going on. On my index page i got 3 links (national flags) when i click 1 my class gets the value from the url like this: href="index.php?lang=uk". Now what i am not sure about is how do i make the string: cause my lang files i want to include look like language_uk.php , language_ge.php etc... So i just want to creat that string and pass it back to my index page in a value so i can include then the right file.

Comment: Side note: Dont name your classes class_whatever and use uppercase first; so it should be `class Lang {}`

Comment: thanks but any idea how to make that string ,sir?

Comment: public function select_lang($var);

        return ('language_'.$this->select_lang($var));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, this should work:

```
return 'language_' . $this->language;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make public var $language ,
construct could filter and validate the GET var, save the object somewhere (sessions) to interact with object
additional methods you could use are
ChangeLang
SetLang
LoadLangFile
SaveToSession
many other..

Answer (score 0):

(1) In PHP, field members are declared with leading "$", but, later, witouth it, and prefixed with "$this->". So:

```
$language;
```

Becomes:

```
$this->language
```

(2) Extra, remove the semicolon from the method header:

```
public function select_lang($var)
{
   return ('language_' . $this->language($var));
}
```

(3) Extra, add a temporally variable to methods that return a value, its not required by syntax, but, will allow you to debug ("ToString"), and avoid a lot of problems:

```
public function select_lang($var)
{
   $Result = ('language_' . $this->language)
   return $Result;
}
```

Cheers.